# How to realize AR-GARCH model with Gram-Charlier distribution in R

Tags: python, r, matlab, distribution, fgarch

I want to use the AR(1)-GARCH(1,1) model where the innovation term is Gram-Charlier distribution;
[This distribution is based on the standard normal distribution, u(z)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPjgU.png)
The software I use is R, but the parameters of the functions in the rugarch package in R with respect to distributions do not provide the option of Gram-Charlier distribution.

```
sGARCHspec = ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(1, 0), 
                                      include.mean = TRUE), 
                    variance.model = list(model = 'sGARCH', 
                                          garchOrder = c(1, 1)), 
                    distribution.model = 'ged')
sGARCHfit = ugarchfit(sGARCHspec, data = df$rate, solver = 'hybrid')
```

[The option of distribution.model in rugarch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QALI.png)

I searched a lot, tried a lot, but couldn't solve it. How can I solve this problem？
I can also use other programming languages, such as python and MATLAB.
Is there any program to set the garch model of innovation term distribution by myself? I will refer to it for study.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.